# OpenGL GLSL hierarchical scaling

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, scale

I am recently writing a humanoid animation system in OpenGL+GLSL. The humanoid representation is a hierarchical transformation system. Many bones do local rotation, translation and scaling. When they are drawn, local transformations are multiplied to obtain global transformations. The global transformations has been past to shader to transform vertexes. It works great when there are only rotation and translation. I implemented IK + interpolation. However, recently one of my mentor points out the system needs a scaling function for bones. This totally messed up the system.

I store local translation vector, rotation quaternion and scale vector in a bone. Then multiple them by the order of TRS to get a local transformation matrix. Obversely, however, the scaling will be carried out to all children nodes. I attempted to remove the parent node scaling by multiplying the inverse of parent node's scaling matrix. It was ok without rotation, but with rotation everything is messed up. All the scaling is only working with global axis but no the expected locally axis scaling. Children nodes also have been scaled badly...Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: I found one problem, i shouldn't use the scale of parent, I should extract the scaling from global transformation. I am trying that...

Comment: the problem looks like between the local scaling and the global scaling.